# Compressing images uploaded to asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, image

I wanted to know what is the best approach of compressing/lowering quality of a JPG/PNG uploaded to my web application.
I allow a few MB for each file, but I want to save it locally on the server as small size as possible, but either compressing it or lowering its quality.
I do not want to resize it.

Should I consider always to conver JPG to PNG hence having smaller size?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend taking a look at a library like [**imageresizer**](http://imageresizing.net/) to do this; you'll have the flexbility to perform whatever kind of resizing you want to do.

Comment: I dont want resize. I want compression/lowering quality

Comment: It also allows you to set the compression amount for jpegs with the quality setting. PNGs are larger than Jpegs for photos, but can be smaller for cartoon graphics, diagrams, etc.

Comment: For example, "format=jpg;quality=75" will convert to jpeg and lower the quality, while "format=png" will convert to png. You can also make an 8-bit PNG with "format=png;colors=256", which may be smaller (requires the PrettyGifs plugin, though).